# WordPress Post Next and Previous Links

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a blog on WordPress, there are around 70,000 posts. Each post have Next and Previous button, Right now, If I click on Next or Previous it goes to a random page.

What I want is, If user clicks on Next, they should seen next post in line, and not random one. Posts are as A, B, C, D.. So if he/she click on next from B post, then it should get directed to C and not A, or D.. and same for previous, If he/she clicks on previous from C, then it should get directed to B, and not A or D.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_next_post_link/?

Comment: there must be something wrong in your prev next post function in your theme / plugin.. try use another theme which has same function ( prev / next ) posts. ie: iconic-one free theme